# Displaying return value of a function in JQuery in another function

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery which is retunring an array of LockedProjects [] which is decalred as global variable.

```
var LockedProjects = [];
```

I wanted to display the values of this array LockedProjects in another JQuery I m accesing this array of values in an alert box to display and separating them with comma. Before displaying that I am checking the length of it.

```
if(LockedProjects.length>0)
alert(LockedProjecrs.join(,));
```

'if' condition is passed But It is not displaying any values. Can  any one help on this?

Comment: syntax error `,` isn't a string. `","` is.

Answer (score 1):

`join()` expects string, you've given it a comma. Also, 'LockedProjects' is spelt incorrectly. I believe it should be:

```
alert(LockedProjects.join(","));
```

Comment: I am using like this only. I kept within double quotes still it did nt work

Comment: Can you re-produce the issue? Perhaps on http://jsfiddle.net? See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lv2V/)

Answer (score 0):

The default separator for [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is `,` so you could simply do

```
LockedProjects.join()
```

> The separator is converted to a string if necessary. If omitted, the array elements are separated with a comma.